# iOS. Protect settings from reset after application updating?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, plist

I use "plist" files to store my settings. The only answer I found is to save the files from this directory:

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

But I don't know how to do that thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the docs: [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for
>   interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an
>   application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences.
>   For example, you can allow users to determine what units of
>   measurement your application displays or how often documents are
>   automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning
>   values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database. The
>   parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to
>   determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts
>   by default.

So you can save and read your settings in and from NSUserDefaults.

```
//write to standard defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourObject forKey:@"kYourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//read from standard defaults
yourObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kYourKey"];
```

Next time try to be more specific of what you want to do.